# Heroku Error method=GET path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Im trying to build a Pinteresting clone using Ruby on Rails.

It all works offline but when on heroku i get this error when i click on "New Pin" found here https://fathomless-hamlet-4281.herokuapp.com/pins

I have run heroku run rake:db migrate

When i run heroku logs --tail this is what comes up when i click the button.

Anyone have any clues? Thanks alot.

```
←[36m2015-02-19T10:29:05.656883+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-02-19T10:29:05.656885+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[33m2015-02-19T10:29:05.953458+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET path="/pins/new" host=fathomless-hamlet-4281.herokuapp.com request_id=5259a5f0-869a-41cb-b360-a27c8b59dd0d fwd="101.167.115.4" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=1754
←[36m2015-02-19T10:29:05.946125+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/pins/new" for 101.167.115.4 at 2015-02-19 10:29:05 +0000
←[36m2015-02-19T10:29:05.951561+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
←[36m2015-02-19T10:29:05.948081+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsController#new as HTML
←[36m2015-02-19T10:29:05.952642+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-02-19T10:29:05.952645+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: user_id):
←[36m2015-02-19T10:29:05.952647+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:14:in `new'
←[36m2015-02-19T10:29:05.952648+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-02-19T10:29:05.952650+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
```

Here is my pins controller:

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
end
```

Here is my views>pins>index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing pins</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= image_tag pin.image.url (:medium) %></td>
        <td><%= pin.description %></td>
        <td><%= pin.user.email if pin.user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', pin %></td>
        <% if pin.user == current_user %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        <% end %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to 'New Pin', new_pin_path %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'New Pin', new_pin_path %>
```

Below is Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150210113737) do

  create_table "pins", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  add_index "pins", ["user_id"], name: "index_pins_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Below is 20150205130111_add_user_id_to_pins

```
class AddUserIdToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pins, :user_id, :interger
    add_index :pins, :user_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post up (ie add to your question) the code for your `PinsController#new` action, highlighting line 14 (which it is saying is where the error occurs)

Comment: `user_id` is not present `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttribute` Error means that you're missing `user_id` in the table of ur db.

Comment: I have added pinscroller and 20150205130111_add_user_id_to_pins files to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_id` is not present `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttribute` Error means that you're missing `user_id` in the table pins .

create a migration

```
bundle exec rails generate migration AddUserIdToPins user_id:integer
```

Then

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Then

```
heroku restart
```

if you have already file then please remove the file and commit it to `heroku` first

`del c:/Users/Joey/desktop/pinteresting/db/migrat e/20150205130111_add_user_id_to_pins.rb`,

Then do 
`bundle exec rails generate migration AddUserIdToPins user_id:integer`

and then

`bundle exec rake db:migrate` 
and 
`git rm old_migration_file` and

`git add new_migration_file` and

`git push heroku master`

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

In your controller code please also chnage

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image, :user_id)
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did that i get an error 

$ rails generate migration AddUserIdToPins user_id:integer
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
      invoke  active_record
    conflict    db/migrate/20150219105216_add_user_id_to_pins.rb
Another migration is already named add_user_id_to_pins: c:/Users/Joey/desktop/pinteresting/db/migrat
e/20150205130111_add_user_id_to_pins.rb. Use --force to replace this migration file.

Comment: if you have already file then please remove the file and commit it to heroku first   `del c:/Users/Joey/desktop/pinteresting/db/migrat e/20150205130111_add_user_id_to_pins.rb`,   Then do `bundle exec rails generate migration AddUserIdToPins user_id:integer ` and then `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and `git rm old_migration_file` and  `git add new_migration_file` and `git push heroku master`

Comment: can you please show me `heroku run rails console` and Then `Pin` hope pins table has already `user_id` also please do `params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image, :user_id)`

Comment: I think i did what you said right. I get this now. http://postimg.org/delete/pdh9b9uk2/

Comment: yes I got it your tables are not created please run `heroku run rake db:migrate` successfully

Comment: did you commit your `database.yml` please also check `database.yml` production database name , adapter and username and pwd

Comment: Once i run bundle exec rake db:migrate theres problems. http://postimg.org/delete/a6wicksau/

Comment: please run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: OMG look at this. http://postimg.org/image/4zlhex6mj/0cf923a5/. Integer is splet interger

Comment: yes please make it integer and commit it and push it to heroku and again run heroku rake db:migrate

Comment: I looked around and dont know how? Thanks Rag.

My mirgrate add_user_id_to_pins file looks like this:

class AddUserIdToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pins, :user_id, :integer
  end
end

Answer (score 1):

I guess, lease Restart your server after migration will refresh the schema cache.

> [heroku restart](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake)

If you dont find solution then
You're getting UnknownAttributeError because you don't have a column in your pins table called user_id

Comment: Ah, yes, if he has just added the `user_id` field in a migration then you may be right.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Could you vote me If you are satisfied with my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for reply guys. I did heroku restart it didn't work.

I will update the post to include schema.rb. I'm assuming that's how you can tell if user id field is there?

Comment: Yes, please cross check if you added migration file in commit or not